# Conectar a servidor MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql

estoy creando una pequeña aplicación para conectarme a mi servidor MySQL local y hacer un SHOW DATABASES y así poder llenar un ComboBox con todas las bases de datos que hay y en base a eso, llenar a su vez, otro combo con todas las tablas de esa BD.

Pero cuando hago la consulta me devuelve un nullPointer porque parece que no se está conectando a mi servidor.

adjunto código de conexión y de consulta.

Variables de conxion:

```
private static final String DDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";

private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASS = "1234";

public static void conecta() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    try {
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt = conexion.createStatement();


    } catch (SQLException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Donde hago la llamada al método

```
public void llenarComboBD() throws SQLException{
    MySQL.ejecutaConsulta("show databases");
    while(MySQL.getRs().next()){
        System.out.println(MySQL.getRs().getString(0));
    }
}
```

Método ejecutaConsulta

```
public static void ejecutaConsulta(String consulta) {
    try {
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);
        meta = rs.getMetaData();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MySQL.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Mi pregunta es, como puedo conectarme al servidor sin tener que seleccionar la BD, ya que creo que me está dando un nullPointer en el resultSet porque no hay seleccionada una BD. El null pointer lo da en la línea:`rs = stmt.executeQuery(consulta);` del método ejecutaConsulta y no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano y un saludo

**SOLUCIÓN**

En el método donde llenaba el combo, no se estaba conectando a la BD, al ser una clase estática, no le estaba pasando a ventana ninguna instancia de la conexión ya que no la necesita por ser una clase estática, pero si necesitaba conectarse, pues he introducido la línea de conexión en el método de llenar el combo y ya.

```
public void llenarComboBD() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        MySQL.conecta("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "1234");
        MySQL.ejecutaConsulta("show databases");
        ResultSet rs = MySQL.getRs();
        //MySQL.getMeta();

        while(rs.next()){
            //String bd = rs.getString(1);
            jcBD.add());
        }

}
```

Comment: Vale, ya lo he conseguido. Gracias de todas formas. Adjunto solución en el comentario principal con una edición.

Comment: Pon la solución en la respuesta y márcala como correcta, así las demás personas verán que ya solucionaste tu problema y no perderán el tiempo, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN**

En el método donde llenaba el combo, no se estaba conectando a la BD, al ser una clase estática, no le estaba pasando a ventana ninguna instancia de la conexión ya que no la necesita por ser una clase estática, pero si necesitaba conectarse, pues he introducido la línea de conexión en el método de llenar el combo y ya.

```
public void llenarComboBD() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        MySQL.conecta("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "1234");
        MySQL.ejecutaConsulta("show databases");
        ResultSet rs = MySQL.getRs();
        //MySQL.getMeta();
    while(rs.next()){
        //String bd = rs.getString(1);
        jcBD.add());
    }
```

}